# List or ArrayList of referenced and references tables with Java and SQL and Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, arraylist

I am trying to get in a ArrayList (for example) a complete list with the tables that another table references and this is referenced by the other tables.

I am looking for a function in Java which have an entry (the table that I want to find) and a result (the ArrayList).

The header of function would be something like this:

```
private static ArrayList<String> name_tables (String table) { ... }
```

And I want that the function return me a list of the tables that `table` is referenced by another tables and `table` references other tables. It will be like the tables that contain a foreign key of `table` and the foreign keys that `table` has of other tables.

How I can implement it in Java with Oracle?

Comment: You are looking for [`getImportedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [`getExportedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: But I don't want the foreign or primary key of the tables, I want the names of the tables that contain its, and I don't have either the foreigns or primary keys, I only have a name of one table

Comment: Those calls **do** return the name of the table, please read the JavaDocs carefully. That is the only Java API that can return such information. If you don't want that, you'll need to create your own query retrieving that information from `all_constraints`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test.parent_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE test.child_table (
  id        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT REFERENCES parent_table ( id ),
  prev_id   INT REFERENCES child_table ( id )
);
```

**Java Code**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DescribeDB {
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    try{
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
                         "username",
                         "password"
                       );

      DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();

      ResultSet rs = md.getImportedKeys(
                          con.getCatalog(),
                          "TEST",
                          "CHILD_TABLE"
                        );

      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "%s.%s.%s references %s.%s.%s",
                rs.getString("FKTABLE_SCHEM"),
                rs.getString("FKTABLE_NAME"),
                rs.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"),
                rs.getString("PKTABLE_SCHEM"),
                rs.getString("PKTABLE_NAME"),
                rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME")
            )
        );
      }
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
TEST.CHILD_TABLE.PREV_ID references TEST.CHILD_TABLE.ID
TEST.CHILD_TABLE.PARENT_ID references TEST.PARENT_TABLE.ID
```

Comment: Thank so much for your code! It is very helpful for me! Only one thing more, would have another thing to do this in an iterative way? I put a table and this check the table that I put first and secondly one of the table that it references and thirdly another table that it references and so continuosly

Comment: Just wrap the functionality above in a helper function (you can maintain the same connection between queries) that returns a list of schema & table name pairs with each call and then maintain a data structure (list/stack/etc) of these pairs and perform a depth- (or breadth-) first search of the structure. You just need to make sure you do not visit the same table twice otherwise you could end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank so much again. I am very clumsy with Java... could you rough out an example of the function that I will have to implement?

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You can try writing it and if you have issues then post a new question with the code you have tried and the problems with it.